# GET value from uicomponent field MAGENTO 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, fieldsets

Do anyone know how to get current input value from uicomponent?

For the case, I have a field (input component) and a button in ui component fieldset. If I click the button, how do I take the input value and open the link in the new tab?